# Esconder imagem gerada pelo Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou a usar a plugin do sharethis para fazer a partilha de conteudo nas redes sociais. Para isso estou a fazer a seguinte chamada:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#username=YOUR_PUBLISHER_ID"></script>
```

O problema é que este código gera uma imagem, e queria usar umas imagens de partilha minhas:

```
<img width="125" border="0" height="16" alt="Share" src="//ct1.addthis.com/static/btn/v2/lg-share-pt.gif"></img>
```

É possível esconder a imagem em javascript? Para esconder a imagem estou a tentar da seguinte maneira mas não resulta:

```
<script>
 $('#teste2').find('img[src$="//ct1.addthis.com/static/btn/v2/lg-share-pt.gif"]').css('visibility', 'hidden');
</script>
```

Encontrei este exemplo na net, e consegui modifica-lo para o que queria. Mas neste caso não estou a conseguir, não sei se será pelo caminho da imagem gerada.

http://jsfiddle.net/bTf7K/162/

A questão é que as minhas imagens aparecem correctamente e fazem a partilha, mas também é adicionada a imagem a cima e queria esconde-la.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eu sugiro fazer uma procura às imagens que têm o dominio shareit no seu url (src) e escondê-las.

```
$('.sortEleWrapper img').each(function () {
    if (this.src.split('addthis.com/static/')[1]) this.style.display = 'none';
});
```

Neste caso usei o `.sortEleWrapper` como elemento ancestral/pai, mas se houver um mais perto meljor. A ideia é procurar todas as imagens dentro desse elemento e seus descendentes e esconder aqueles que têm uma parte do `src` contendo esta string `addthis.com/static/`

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/29bTQ/)

Outra ideia é pôr o script dentro de uma div "escudo"/wrapper e colocar no CSS uma regra para escondêr imagens que aí estejam com `#escudo img{display: none;}`

[**Exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/U7WTt/)

Comment: isso funciona bem, o problema é que ele está a carregar a imagem do sharethis no fim de carregar a página (penso eu). Logo não me está a esconder a imagem

Comment: @pc_oc, juntei uma outra ideia.

Comment: Já consegui, a partir da ultima ideia. Mais uma vez obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

Uma ideia seria incluíres o ficheiro de `script` fazendo uso do `$.getScript()` de forma a incluíres o plugin do sharethis na página.

Desta forma podes estar atento e saber quando o mesmo foi carregado, executando assim o código para localizar e esconder a imagem:

```
var endereco = "http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#username=YOUR_PUBLISHER_ID";

$.getScript( endereco )
.done(function( script, textStatus ) {
    // correu bem, localizar e esconder imagem que contém X
    $("img[src*='addthis.com']").hide();
})
.fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
    // correu mal, agir em conformidade
});
```

---

**Informações úteis:**

- [jQuery $.getScript()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) <sup>Inglês</sup>
- [jQuery Attribute Contains Selector [name*="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) <sup>Inglês</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Seu código não está completo.

Mas tente fazer a alteração pelo CSS.

```
.st_sharethis_custom{
   background: url("imagem.jpg") no-repeat;
   padding:0px 16px 0 0;
}
```